# Corona sdk display.captureScreen() to save later

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am using the display.capureScreen() to take a picture of the users final score. After that happens, a window pops up showing their coins, score, high score, and the picture that was just captured. When I do this:

```
 screenCap = display.captureScreen(true)
```

It saves the picture to the photo library because it is set to true. My question is how could I not save this automatically, but only if the user wants to, using a "save picture" button?

Comment: @Schollii Yes, that causes it to not save, but is it possible to display the screen capture, but then save it later to the photo library? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display.save(object, filename)` to save the display object returned by `captureScreen()`:

```
local image = display.captureScreen()
image:toBack() -- hide it 

... do stuff...

display.save( image, { filename="image.png", isFullResolution=true } )
image:removeSelf() -- no longer need it
image = nil
```

Image must be in display hierarchy when you save it.

If you want to save to the photo album later, then `display.save` doesn't give you that option, you have to use `display.capture` or `display.captureBounds`. Example:

```
local image = display.captureScreen()
image:toBack() -- hide it 

... do stuff...

local capture = display.capture( image, { saveToPhotoLibrary=true, isFullResolution=true } )
-- cleanup
capture:removeSelf()
capture = nil
image:removeSelf()
image = nil
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using display.capture() to save screenCap because display.save() does not save it to the photo album.

Comment: @SamHogan That wasn't in your question but ok, I have updated to cover that case too